# How can i load php file after sending ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have 2 files file1.php with all the php and ajax, and file2.php with only php.

`$_POST["there_id"]` will be sent from file1.php page to file2.php through ajax.

file1.php code:

```
<div class="list_items">
    <a href="" class="box" id="56545"><li><p>content here ...</p></a>
</div>

<div class="content_area">
    //load ajax content here
</div>

$(".box").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var there_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "indexnew.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { there_id : there_id}
    });
});
```

file2.php code:

```
<div id="file2content>
<?php
    $there_id = $_POST['there_id'];
    $user_id = 5; 
    $fetch_data = regular_query("SELECT * FROM contents WHERE 
    (user_by = :me or user_by + :them) AND (user_to = :me or user_to = :them)", 
    ["me" => $user_id, "them" = $there_id], $conn);

    foreach ($fetch_data as $data) : ?>

    <a href=""><li><p>database data here</p></a>

<?php
     endforeach;
?>

</div>
```

now what i want to do is when file2.php is done with php and list items are available i want to load `file2contents` to `content_area` on file1.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".box").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var there_id = $(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax({
       url: "indexnew.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { there_id : there_id},
       success: function(data) {
           $('.content_area').html(data);
       }
   });
});
```

However, `content_area` should really be an id rather than a class so that it's unique.

Since you're just returning html, you can simplify it using the `.load()` function.

```
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var there_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.content_area').load('indexnew.php', {there_id: there_id});
});
```

Comment: both of us forgot to point out that the Javascript really needs to reside within <script></script> tags if its to do anything at all :')

Comment: so the function(data) is everything in file2.php?

Comment: @this.Tony the data returned would be the raw DATA that the Ajax Call Returns.-- I say RAW unless JSON and the Ajax Call automatically parsed it.

Comment: @this.Tony you can use anything you want there if it's confusing. `function(d) { $('.content_area').html(d); }` works just as well. It's the return data in this case.

Comment: @mawburn ohyeah i know but that parameter carries everything from the file2.php right

Comment: also @mawburn I'm liking the Alternative, shorthand approach.

Comment: it carries a string containing the data that you'd see if you did that request yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's the contents of the AJAX call. As t3chguy mentioned, it doesn't have to be html it can be json and automatically parsed. To do that you would define `dataType: "json"` in your `$.ajax` settings. Otherwise it's just raw data (in this case HTML)

Comment: Typically shouldn't need to define the dataType, just the headers and it will automatically guess from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) { $(".content_area").html(data); }
```

adding the above to your AJAX call should do what you want if I understand you correctly.